# How to select an item from a set with constraints, and finding when the pattern repeats.

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, permutations, pattern-recognition

I am trying to solve the following problem with constraints that are explained below.

Assume there are customers walking into a restaurant and you want to assign them to different waiters.  With the waiters having the following weights.

```
W1  W2  W3  W4  W5
1   2   2   3   5
```

What this implies is that W1 will get the 1st customer in every sequence of customers, W2 and W3 will get one customer in every other sequence, W4 will get a customer in every 3rd sequence, and W5 will get a customer in every 5th sequence.

A new sequence is started after every waiter in the prior sequence has received a customer.

Below is also a sample of the distribution of the customers to sequences and waiters and after that a description of each sequence.

```
Seq  W1  W2  W3  W4  W5
 1   C1
 2   C2  C3  C4
 3   C5          C6
 4   C7  C8  C9
 5   C10             C11
 6   C12 C12 C13 C14
 7   C15
 8   C18 C19 C20
 9   C21         C22
10   C23 C24 C25     C25
```

1. SEQ1 - Assign to waiters with weight = 1
2. SEQ2 - Assign to waiters with weight = 1,2
3. SEQ3 - Assign to waiters with weight = 1,3
4. SEQ4 - Assign to waiters with weight = 1,2
5. SEQ5 - Assign to waiters with weight = 1,5
6. SEQ6 - Assign to waiters with weight = 1,2,3

The above table is flattened as follows:

```
Customer    W1  W2  W3  W4  W5
  1         X               
  2         X               
  3             X           
  4                 X
  5         X       
  6                     X
  7         X       
  8             X   
  9                 X
  10        X           
  11                        X
  12        X           
  13            X       
  14                X   
  15                    X
  16        X           
  17        X           
  18            X       
  19                X   
  20        X           
  21                    X
  22        X           
  23            X       
  24                X   
  25                        X
```

Now, given the **just** the customer number and weightings, is it possible to find which waiter to assign the customer to and is there a generic way of doing this with different weights and different number of waiters ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $S_n$ be the total number of customers after $n$ sequences and $W_1$, $W_2$ ... $W_m$ be the weight of the waitors:

$$S_n=\sum_{i=1}^m\left\lfloor\frac{n}{W_i}\right\rfloor$$

You can prove it by considering each waitor separately. Each waitor contributes $\left\lfloor n/W_i\right\rfloor$ to the total. $S_n$ is just the sum of these integer divisions.

You noticed such systems are periodic. If a pattern has a period of $n$ sequence numbers, it also repeats every $kn$ sequence numbers where $k$ is any positive integer. Every waitor creates a pattern with a period of $W_i$ sequences. And the period of the system is just the smallest repeating interval for all waitors. We can conclude that the period is the lowest common multiple of all $W_i$. This gives you:

$$p=LCM\{1,2,2,3,5\}=30$$

You can then get the number of customers per cycle which is $S_p$. Note that since $p$ is divisible by all $W_i$, the terms do not need to be floored:

$$S_p
=\sum_{i=1}^m\left\lfloor\frac{p}{W_i}\right\rfloor
=\sum_{i=1}^m\frac{p}{W_i}
=30/1+30/2+30/2+30/3+30/5=76$$

Now we can look at the more difficult problem of finding what sequence a customer $k$ belongs to. We'll denote this as $f(k)$. It can be characterised as the minimal function that satisfies:

$$k\leq S_{f(k)}$$

Finding a neat closed form formula for $f(k)$ would prove too difficult.

EDIT: Restricting the domain didn't seem helpful, especially for calculating by hand, so I've removed it.

Try this. Calculate:
$$\left\lceil\frac{C\times p}{S_p}\right\rceil$$

This tends to be a very good estimate. If it doesn't get the right answer, usually you only have to increment it once or twice although sometimes more.

Comment: Chris, I have updated my question to make it clearer. What I'm trying to figure out is, given the weightings and a customer, say C37, determine which waiter to assign to. Again, knowing only the number of waiters, the weightings and customer number.

Comment: I'm afraid, unless you'd like a python script or something which implements an algorithm, I don't think I can do any better than this edit.

Comment: If you have a script that would be awesome. I am actually trying to implement it in java, but any language would do.

Comment: Using the edit you provided, if for example i try it for C20 it would give (20*30)/76=7.8. Which doesn't really make any sense to me, since we are trying to find which waiter this should go to and for that particular customer ,number 20, we can see from the list above, it should be assigned to W1.

Comment: Chris, I just wanted to update you that, I have been able to get your formula to work. What is strange is that the original formula you had put should have worked. However, I was able to get approximate the sequence by just doing  c * (k/Sp), which strangely enough gives the same result as your previous formula of f(k)= f(k mod Sp) + p*(k/Sp).  Anyways, once I can approximate the sequence, then I can figure out which waiter the request goes to by figuring out the total customers in the approximated sequence +-1 and the current customer number